# Cube moving through rigidbody

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, unityscript, rigid-bodies

In unity 5.1.1f1
I have a cube which is moving by a script. Whenever a rigidbody comes in contact to it, it moves the rigidbody out of its path.

However in some of the situations, the rigidBody is in the path of the cube and the cube moves through the rigidbody.

For example as here in the pic, the red is the movable cube and the grey is the RigidBody - [image]

As you can see the red cube can move into the grey rigidBody.

The sources are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/axrdyin8sdgtj0a/Assets.zip?dl=0)

I also asked the question [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1015542/cube-moving-through-rigid-body.html)

The cube is moving with the script -

```
 transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, 
 patrolPoints [currentPoint].position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurs because your rigidbody (blue cube) becomes asleep. This can be fixed by adding GetComponent ().sleepThreshold = -1; to Start() method of you PlayerMovement.cs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Collision Detection is set to continous.

Answer (score 0):

### Correct Answer

Sorry i didnt realize it was the object without rigidbody you intend to move. If this is the case, and you must use `Vector3.MoveTowards()` or `transform.Translate()`, then do so in `FixedUpdate()` function instead of `Update()` and use `Time.fixedDeltaTime` instead of `Time.deltaTime` this will put your movements in increments synced up to Unity's physics frames, which happen at different intervals from the rendered frames. This is not a bug.

### Original Answer

You dont want to use `Vector3.MoveTowards()` or `transform.Translate()` with rigidbodies which you want to interact with other bodies. They will move exactly the way you tell them without any interaction. You need to use `rigidbody.AddForce()` instead.

Comment: In the question, the red movable cube is not a rigidBody. It is just a cube. Should I move the cube using something like Object.AddForce()

Answer (score 0):

Adding rigidBody to the red cube solved the problem.

Should I put this problem statement in the unity bugs?